# Alignment of images

Tags: html

I am fairly new at this, so, this may seem like a very simple question to answer.

I've started to design my own page, and the code below is where I am at so far.

How it's looks is...

- top left - my logo
- top right - navigation
- left hand side - images / descriptions

What I am trying to do, and where I am getting stuck, is getting the description to align perfectly underneath each image, and have that same thing happen as you move right across the page.

What is currently happening is that each image, and description underneath, are aligning on the left all the way down the left side of the page.

Current code below:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#"><img src="#" alt="Title" width="300" height="100" /></a>
    <div id="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="images">
      <img src="#" width="300" height="199" alt="name"></div>
      <div id="descriptions">City</div>
      <div id="images">
        <img src="#" width="300" height="199" alt="name"></div>
        <div id="descriptions">Model</div>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @chinna_82 It's not tabular data. Only use tables for tabular data. There are dozens of other ways to do this without tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use markup like this:

```
<figure class="images">
    <img src="#" width="300" height="199" alt="City">
    <figcaption>City</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="images">
    <img src="#" width="300" height="199" alt="Model">
    <figcaption>Model</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="images">
    <img src="#" width="300" height="199" alt="Foo">
    <figcaption>Foo</figcaption>
</figure>
```

And some sample CSS:

```css
.images {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    min-height: 200px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    background-color: #EEE; /* just to show containers since image scr is blank */
}

.images:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.images figcaption {
    text-align: center;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LU5xt/)

Comment: that's great! it worked out well! thank you so much. i have a few other questions: 1) how would the above change if i wanted to have a quadrant of 4 pictures on the left, so basically, 2 pictures on top and 2 pictures on the bottom; 2) what would i do if i have that quadrant on the left and wanted to put a section on the right which presented text during a roll over of the different pictures; and 3) how do i extend the white background color where the first image and the navbar is around the other images...I created a container with white background and a gray background for the rest.

Comment: @user1912669 For the first case, you could remove the `:last-child` rule and add: `.images:nth-child(2) { margin-right: 0; }` and an additional rule to clear the floats: `.images:nth-child(3) { clear: left; }`. Your other questions are probably best handled as a new question. Create a concise example for each and create new questions.